# How do I get frameworks and libraries for other iOS versions in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

In my iOS application in XCode 6, I:

1. Click on the application name in the file browser on the left-hand side
2. Go to the "General" tab
3. Go to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section
4. Click the "+" to add a framework

In the list it gives me, all frameworks and libraries are nested under "iOS 8.0".

I want frameworks and libraries for earlier iOS versions. How do I get those? What determines the things in the list of frameworks and libraries?

Comment: Why do you think you need libraries and frameworks from earlier versions of iOS? Give an example.

Comment: Do you just want to support earlier versions of iOS? If that's the case, just change your Deployment Target to an earlier version.

Comment: If you still believe you need access to older frameworks after rmaddy and timgcarlson suggestions, then you can always download older versions of Xcode.  https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode

Comment: @rmaddy my Deployment Target is set to 7.1, which means I'm developing for iOS 7.1. This is my intention -- I do not intend to develop for iOS 8.0. I can't use iOS 8.0 frameworks for an iOS 7.1 application. Therefore I expect there to be frameworks available for iOS 7.1, but these are not in the list.